# IE webdriver of Selenium Python loads the webpage and goes to a halt state

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

Hey there Python Experts,
I have used Beautiful Soup and REquests to scrape data from static web for my project. But for Dynamic contents i am unable to do the same. I have installed selenium for the same. But when i execute the below code; The code goes to sleep mode after opening browser. I can see only '1Test' in my op window.

Please help :)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='IEDriverServer_Win32_3.150.1/IEDriverServer.exe')
print('1test')
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
print('2test')
driver.close()
print('3test')
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to temporarily stop the execution of the program by using

`driver.sleep(<number of seconds>)`

or by importing the time module and writing

`time.sleep(<number of seconds>)`

this needs to be done after every step.

this needs to be done the different elements on a webpage need time to load up and hence if called before they are fully loaded, selenium will not be able to access them and will raise a error

Comment: Thank you Aklon. Time.Sleep method worked for me :)